# Routing error when trying to use same view for update and create flows (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

**My overall use case:**

I have a **Listing** model that has many **images**. The Listing detail page lists all the fields that can be updated inline (through ajax).

I want to be able to use the same view for both **update listing** and **create new listing**.

My listing controller looks as follows:

```
 def detail 
     @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])  
     @image = Image.new #should this link somewhere else?

     respond_to do |format| 
         format.html # show.html.erb  
         format.xml { render :xml => @listing } 
      end 
 end 


  def create
      # create a new listing and save it immediately. Assign it to guest, with a status of "draft"
      @listing = Listing.new(:price_id => 1)  # Default price id
      # save it to db
      # TODO add validation that it has to have a price ID, on record creation. So the view doesn't break.
      @listing.save
      @image = Image.new

      # redirect_to "/listings/detail/@listing.id" #this didn't work

      respond_to do |format| 
          format.html # show.html.erb  
          format.xml { render :xml => @listing } 
      end
 end
```

**The PROBLEM** 
I'm using a partial that shows the same form for the create view and the detail view.

This works perfectly except for one thing:
When I pull up 
http://0.0.0.0:3000/listings/detail/7, it works perfectly.

When I pull up 
http://0.0.0.0:3000/listings/new, I get the following error:

Showing /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rails_testing/feedbackd/app/views/listings/_edit_form.html.erb where line #100 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"images"}
Extracted source (around line #100):

```
97: <!-- Form for new images -->
98: <div class="span-20 append-bottom">
99: <!-- <%# form_for :image, @image, :url => image_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %> -->
100: <%= form_for @image, :url => image_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
101:     <%= f.text_field :description %><br />
102:  <%= f.file_field :photo %>
103:  <%= submit_tag "Upload" %>
```

**What I think the issue is:**
When I upload a new image (I'm using Paperclip), it requires the listing_id to create the image record. Since the listing_id isn't passed in with **listings/new** it can't find the listing_id. How can I pass in the id? Via a redirect? What's the best way to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: are you sure with your routes.rb file?

Comment: Are you suggesting I just fix my route, or hardcore the URL I want to submit to?

Comment: :url => image_path is useless in the form declaration

Comment: @apneadiving Is the image_path useful if there already is an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, your comments have all been helpful.

This is how I wound up solving it:

I added a route for **images/new** to point to **imageController -> Create**

```
<%= form_for @image, :url => "/images/new/#{@listing.id}" , :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :description %><br />
<%= f.file_field :photo %>
<%= submit_tag "Upload" %>
```

<% end %>

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem is that you are trying to submit to a URL that doesn't exist.  If you use a form like this:

```
<%= form_for @image, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
```

Then in your routes.rb file you should have:

```
resources :images
```

And you should have an ImagesController with a create action defined.  The ImagesController#create action will get called when you submit this form.

Comment: I already had the resources defined like this. When I removed the :url => "..." it worked great for http://0.0.0.0:3000/listings/detail/7, but failed for http://0.0.0.0:3000/listings/new.

So to fix that, I just hardcoded it in my answer below. +1 for sending me in the right direction.

Comment: You should not have to specify the URL if you have the route defined as "resources :images", because RAILS can figure out that a new Image class should POST to the proper URL.  That said, if you want to specify the route, you should use "images_path" not "image_path", since you want to POST to /images.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in ur routes.rb file. U have not defined the path, thats why it is giving this error. This might help u

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/routing.html#restful-routing-the-rails-default

Comment: The path was defined, although your comment makes sense. +1